# python from ... import ... works but import ... throws TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason import k8s.projects_v2 is not working when I call k8s.projects_v2.Projects() but k8s.projects_v2 import Projects is working when I call Projects.

I have another class which has import k8s.projects_v2 and it is working. All classes are in the same package.

Can somebody please point me in a direction as to why I would get TypeError?PyCharm doesn't show any error/warning for this py file.

Whilst it's working the from/import way I want to understand why it works using import in one but not in another!

I run the following code snippet;

```
import logging
import k8s.instance
import k8s.projects_v2
from typing import Union

CELL_KEY: str = 'cell'

CELLS_KEY: str = 'cells'

EXTENDS_KEY: str = 'extends'


_logging = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Cell(k8s.instance.Instance):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.__projects = k8s.projects_v2.Projects()
```

I get;

```
DEBUG:__main__:Infrastructure.load_from_yaml(<class 'str'>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dick/PycharmProjects/koolie/python/koolie/k8s/infrastructure_v2.py", line 105, in <module>
    infrastructure.load_from_yaml('infrastructure_v2.yaml')
  File "C:/Users/Dick/PycharmProjects/koolie/python/koolie/k8s/infrastructure_v2.py", line 75, in load_from_yaml
    self.load(yaml.load(file))
  File "C:/Users/Dick/PycharmProjects/koolie/python/koolie/k8s/infrastructure_v2.py", line 65, in load
    self.cells.load(data)
  File "C:\Users\Dick\PycharmProjects\koolie\python\koolie\k8s\cells_v2.py", line 58, in load
    cell: Cell = Cell()
  File "C:\Users\Dick\PycharmProjects\koolie\python\koolie\k8s\cells_v2.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.__projects = k8s.projects_v2.Projects()
TypeError: 'Projects' object is not callable
```

Whereas if i run;

```
import logging
import k8s.instance
from k8s.projects_v2 import Projects
from typing import Union

CELL_KEY: str = 'cell'

CELLS_KEY: str = 'cells'

EXTENDS_KEY: str = 'extends'


_logging = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Cell(k8s.instance.Instance):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.__projects = Projects()
```

I get no error!

Comment: can you try to print `k8s.projects_v2.Projects` in the first example and `Projects` in the second example?

Comment: print(k8s.projects_v2.Projects) gives Projects and print(Projects) gives <class 'k8s.projects_v2.Projects'> respectively.

Comment: That's means the namespace is being broken, doesn't it? Because both should print class...

Comment: Where does `k8s` come from?

Comment: Apparently it's your own project. You've done *something* to screw with the import system, likely involving circular imports or overwriting names, but we can't tell from here.

Comment: Is it possible that I'm assigning a value to k8s.projects_v2.Projects prior to the cells.py being accessed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! In infrastructure.py I had the following typo, the last line being a compound assignment. The first '=' should be a ':'. The result being I was assigning the new Projects() object to the Projects class pointer...

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.cells = k8s.cells_v2.Cells()
    self.clusters: k8s.clusters.Clusters = k8s.clusters.Clusters()
    self.tokens: k8s.tokens_v2.Tokens = k8s.tokens_v2.Tokens()
    self.projects = k8s.projects_v2.Projects = k8s.projects_v2.Projects()
```